How to add maxOutputTokens argument to Gemini API request
I want to add maxOutputTokens argument in my code but I don't know how.
import requests


API_KEY = 'INPUT_API_KEY'
API_URL = 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models/gemini-pro:generateContent'


def call_gemini_api(prompt):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-goog-api-key': API_KEY,
    }
    data = {
        'contents': [
            {
                'role': 'model',
                'parts': [{'text': 'You are AI'}]
            },
            {
                'role': 'user',
                'parts': [{'text': prompt}]
            }
        ]
    }
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()

prompt = "Hello"
response = call_gemini_api(prompt)
print(response)


any reason you dont want to use the python library?

There are several things to note about the code you've presented, in addition to your specific question.
First, there are two useful resources to understand the data structure you need to send to Gemini if you're using REST.

Going to Google AI Studio

Adjust the prompts and settings to meet your needs
Select "Get code" in the upper right hand corner
In the window that pops up, change "Python" in the drop down on the left to "cURL" which will show the JSON structure being used in a curl command


The API Documentation is a little (ok, a lot) complicated to read, but does (ultimately) provide the structure and endpoints

Given these, you can see that if you want to adjust maxOutputTokens, you would need to add a new object to your data variable called generationConfig and it would have a maxOutputTokens parameter.
In your code, it might look something like this:
    data = {
        'contents': [
            # contents omitted for clarity
        ],
        'generationConfig': {
            'maxOutputTokens': 1024
        }
    }

However, I want to point out a few other issues with the code that you presented:

The contents array must alternate between "user" and "model" roles, and the "user" role must be both first and last.
You're specifying "v1" in your URL. While this is valid, many of Gemini's features aren't available using v1. You may wish to consider using "v1beta".
You're specifying the "gemini-pro" model. This is, currently, an alias for "gemini-1.0-pro" which is currently an alias for "gemini-1.0-pro-001". Given there are better and cheaper models available, that have more features, such as "gemini-1.5-flex", you may wish to consider switching.

If you have questions about these - open a new Stack Overflow question.
Finally, as noted in the comments, you may want to just consider using the standard python library or some other third party library. Unless you need to use the REST interface manually, the library provides some additional abstractions (such as history) that can make some tasks easier.
